Download file ‘DotNetFX48\NDP48-x86-x64-AIIOS-CHT.exe’ for item ‘Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)’
The installer property Localization is Chinese(Traditional).Localization is Chinese(Traditional)
And in Prerequisites dialog box, I need to install Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8.Prerequisites dialog box
And install location for prerequisites is ‘Download prerequisites from the same location as my application’.
My problem is that I have already put ‘NDP48-x86-x64-AIIOS-CHT.exe’ in the folder: C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX48\
folder(I copy the error message and paste to the file name.)
But when I build the installer there still error like
ERROR: To enable ‘Download prerequisites from the same location as my application’ in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file ‘DotNetFX48\NDP48-x86-x64-AIIOS-CHT.exe’ for item Microsoft .Net Framework 4.8 (x86 and x64)’ to your local machine. For information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616028.
ERROR: General failure building bootstrapper
ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x80004005
error log
How can I fix it?
At first I have the same problem with DotNetFX48\NDP48-x86-x64-AIIOS-ENU.exe and crystal reports runtime engine for .NET Framework . And after I put both them in the folder there just still show the error message of CHT file.
And I tried to set Localization to English but when installing my tradition Chinese is garbled
garbled name
garbled name in desktop
How can I make the name right or how can I fix the localization=chinese(traditional) problem?

Inside the DotNetFX48 folder, there should also be a .xml manifest file. Ensure that the XML file is configured properly and points to the NDP48-x86-x64-AIIOS-CHT.exe file.

I found that it is a location problem.
I have put the CHT file in the wrong folder.
It should be in language folder in DotNetFX48 folder.
Then it can build success.
p1
And the ENU file should be in DotNetFX48 folder.
p2
